# TV Tunner Raw Audio Video Samples

Tags: c#, c++, directshow, video-capture

Is it possible to grab samples from two available TV tuner output which are video and Audio signal. How can i do it programmatically in C# or C++. The tuner supports IAMTvTuner interface and has several methods. Which method will give me data that i can store in char buffer, maybe i need to convert data to char.

For example there is function in Tuner interface for getting signal strength, i think there must be some method to retrieve samples available, if not then how can i write my custom function.
Answer with code example will be really helpful for me.

Comment: take a look at the SampleGrabber filter

Comment: Sample grabber filter is for known media types whereas tuner will be giving raw samples. in grpahedit it gives error to connect tv tuner output pins to SampleGrabber filter. Does it mean it will also not connect programmatically?

Comment: the [tuner filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407249(v=vs.85).aspx) itself can only be connected to a crossbar. And you do not create crossbars and tuner filters manually, but for example using `ICaptureGraphBuilder2::FindInterface`